# WCF error al invocar servicio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

Tengo un problema es una instalacion nueva de VS pero quiero obtener una lista de 2 tablas conectaDAS utilizo la entidad y al momento de debuggear devuelve los valores de la lista monsrando el count pero al momento de mostrar el servicio me da el error,me han comentado que puede ser de configuracion.

"Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP a http://localhost:52132/Service1.svc. Puede deberse a que el enlace del extremo de servicio no usa el protocolo HTTP. También puede deberse a que el servidor anula un contexto de solicitud HTTP (posiblemente por el cierre del servicio). Consulte los registros del servidor para obtener más información.

> Server stack trace: 
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      en IService1.list()
>      en Service1Client.list()
>
> Inner Exception:
>   Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción.
>      en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>
> Inner Exception:
>   No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.
>      en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      en System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      en System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> Inner Exception:
>   Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
>      en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)"

```
namespace servicioNew
{
    // NOTA: puede usar el comando "Rename" del menú "Refactorizar" para cambiar el nombre de clase "Service1" en el código, en svc y en el archivo de configuración.
    // NOTE: para iniciar el Cliente de prueba WCF para probar este servicio, seleccione Service1.svc o Service1.svc.cs en el Explorador de soluciones e inicie la depuración.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        frapuccinoEntities fe = new frapuccinoEntities();

        public List<Alumno> list() {

            List<Alumno> lista = (from q in fe.Alumno
                                     select q).ToList();


            return lista;
        }
    }
}
```

//LA INTERFACE ESTA ASI

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<Alumno> list();
}
```

En la parte del modelo los atributos tienen su `[Datacontract]` y member pero no entiendo el error.

Comment: Has intentado poner un try{}catch{} antes de devolver la lista. Es para que el error no venga disparado desde el origen de datos y o te esté provocando un timeout.

Comment: Al final era algo simple agrege la entidad.configuration.proxyenable = false; y listo, gracias!

Comment: buenas donde agregaste eso que indicas.
Gracias.

Comment: Saludos Zac, ¿Podrías agregar la respuesta por favor? Así serías el héroe de varios usuarios que andan batallando con lo mismo, de paso colaboras con la salud del sitio (% de preguntas con respuestas aceptadas). Gracias :D